# Select or Activate Worksheet before assign it as "byref worksheet"?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Question. I have the following class property:

```
Private myLanguage As String

Public Property Get Language() As String
Language = myLanguage
End Property
Public Property Let Language(ByVal Value As String)
myLanguage = Value
End Property

Public Property Get LanguageColumn(ByRef LanguageWs As Worksheet, _
ByVal LanguageRow As Integer) As Integer
LanguageColumn = LanguageWs.Range(Cells(LanguageRow, 1), Cells(LanguageRow, 250)).Find(myLanguage).Column
End Property
```

Calling that I use

```
Dim cls as new Cls1
cls.LanguageColumn(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1), 1)
```

I get the Error:

> "1004' - Method 'Range' of object'_Workseet' failed

When I change my executing code to:

```
Dim cls as new Cls1
Worksheets(1).Activate
cls.LanguageColumn(ThisWorkbook.Worksheeets(1), 1)
```

It is working. Can anyone tell me why and if I always have to use `.Activate` or `.Select` when I use a `byref worksheet` ?

Comment: can you show your actual code? this line `cls.LanguageColumn(ThisWorkbook.Worksheeets(1), 1)` even not compiled (since it's get property and should be assigned to variable) and also change `Worksheeets`-->`Worksheets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fully qualify your `Cells`, i.e. specify to which sheet `Cells` belongs. Change :

```
LanguageColumn = LanguageWs.Range(Cells(LanguageRow, 1), Cells(LanguageRow, 250)).Find(myLanguage).Column
```

to

```
LanguageColumn = LanguageWs.Range(LanguageWs.Cells(LanguageRow, 1), LanguageWs.Cells(LanguageRow, 250)).Find(myLanguage).Column
```

or better:

```
With LanguageWs
    LanguageColumn = .Range(.Cells(LanguageRow, 1), Cells(.LanguageRow, 250)).Find(myLanguage).Column
End With
```

Also I suggest you to change `ByVal LanguageRow As Integer` to `ByVal LanguageRow As Long` as well as returned type of your property (since max value if `Integer` is only `32768`).

Actually I would use this one for reliability (if `myLanguage` not found):

```
Public Property Get LanguageColumn(ByRef LanguageWs As Worksheet, _
       ByVal LanguageRow As Long) As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    With LanguageWs
        Set rng = .Range("A" & LanguageRow).Resize(, 250).Find(myLanguage)
    End With

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        LanguageColumn = -1
    Else
        LanguageColumn = rng.Column
    End If
End Property
```